# Another control tab in AVD

Tags: android-emulator, android-sdk, avd-manager

I have Android Emulator from Android Studio and from some days I have another basic controls tab (on dark gray background). I don't want it, because it's second tab to controls emulator. Anyone kwow where I can turn it off?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxS1D.jpg

Comment: This is probably answer for my question:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html?utm_source=android-studio#skins

Answer (score 0):

While creating Virtual device when you select "new Hardware profile" then windows open there is option Input. In front of input there is select box "Has Hardware Button" Unchecked that select box.

If you Already created virtual Device 
then edit your Virtual device configuration. There is above mention option when you click Advance settings.
There is an option "hardware back/home keys". Specify the option and set it to "no" when creating the virtual device.